# Type check fails with as-pattern

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-inference, functor

I wrote a `Functor` instance for my custom `Either` type, called `Or`, which works just fine like this:

```
data Or a b = First a
            | Second b
            deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Functor (Or a) where
  fmap _ (First x)  = First x
  fmap f (Second b) = Second $ f b
```

Yet, when I use the as-pattern, the program doesn't typecheck anymore:

```
instance Functor (Or a) where
  fmap _ first@(First _) = first
  fmap f (Second b)      = Second $ f b
```

The error message:

```
error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘a1’ with ‘b’
      ‘a1’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          fmap :: forall a1 b. (a1 -> b) -> Or a a1 -> Or a b
        at /home/me/haskell/functors/src/Lib.hs:139:3-6
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          fmap :: forall a1 b. (a1 -> b) -> Or a a1 -> Or a b
        at /home/me/haskell/functors/src/Lib.hs:139:3-6
      Expected type: Or a b
        Actual type: Or a a1
    • In the expression: first
      In an equation for ‘fmap’: fmap _ first@(First _) = first
      In the instance declaration for ‘Functor (Or a)’
    • Relevant bindings include
        first :: Or a a1
          (bound at /home/me/haskell/functors/src/Lib.hs:139:10)
        fmap :: (a1 -> b) -> Or a a1 -> Or a b
          (bound at /home/me/haskell/functors/src/Lib.hs:139:3)
    |
139 |   fmap _ first@(First _) = first
    |                            ^^^^^
```

This surprises me since I assumed `First x` and `first` to have the same type.

What's the reason for this type error?

I'm using GHC 8.2.2.

Comment: A minimized version of this problem that may be worth thinking about: `good, bad :: Proxy a -> Proxy b; good Proxy = Proxy; bad proxy = proxy`.

Comment: By the way, this turns out to be a problem in Haskell *implementation*, because GHC's main intermediate language (called GHC core) is typed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've stumbled upon a subtle little error. Take a look at the type of `First`.

```
First :: a -> Or a b
```

Now, we usually leave out `forall` quantifiers, but this is true *for all* `a` and `b`. This is going to be important.

```
fmap1 _ (First x) = First x

fmap2 _ first @ (First _) = first
```

Let's apply some explicit type signatures. (The below is not actual Haskell code, as you can't have type signatures in a pattern. But it illustrates the point.)

```
fmap1 :: (b -> c) -> Or a b -> Or a c
fmap1 _ ((First :: a -> Or a b) x) = (First :: a -> Or a c) x

fmap2 :: (b -> c) -> Or a b -> Or a c
fmap2 _ (first :: Or a b) @ (First _) = (first :: Or a b)
```

So in `fmap2`, `first` has type `Or a b`, but you need an `Or a c` to make everything work. In the first example, it *looks* like you're just unapplying and then reapplying `First`, but you're really applying a different (but related) function. It's like how you can do `show 1` and `show "A"`. These are two different calls to two different functions which happen to share the name `show`. In your case, it's a similar concept. The `First` you're extracting is a `Or a b`, but the `First` you construct on the right-hand-side is a `Or a c`.

Comment: With `ScopedTypeVariables`, you can have type signatures in patterns.